# 'Date To' should be the beginning of 'Date From' modal popup jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Hi im using Jqgrid in MVC and the requirement is as such.. In the Model popup of jqgrid to add/edit a row.. I have 4 columns..
***DateFrom***, ***DateTo***, ***Type***, ***Remarks***
And im using jquery datepicker..
**My Requirement**
 After adding the 1st row.. while adding the second row.. the **DateFrom** field(of the second row) should be the next date of **DateTo** field of the previously added row.

This is my Grid

```
    initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "m-d-yy",
                        showOn: "button",
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }, 50);
    },
    initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "m-d-yy ",
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }, 50);
    },

    jQuery("#dateGrid").jqGrid({
            height: 100,
            width: 1000,
            colNames: ['DateFrom', 'DateTo', 'Type', 'Remarks'],
            colModel: [

                {
                    name: 'DateFrom', index: 'DateFrom', width: 60, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'm/d/Y',

                    },
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14 },

                },
                {
                    name: 'DateTo', index: 'DateTo', width: 80, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'm/d/Y',

                    },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14,

                    },

                },
                {
                    name: 'Type', width: 80, editable: true, formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Open:Open;Maintainance:Maintainance;Closed:Closed", defaultValue: "Open" },
                },
                 {
                     name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 80, editable: true
                 }
                ,
            ],
            // multiselect:true,
            pager: "#datePager",
            loadonce: true,
            sortname: 'Client',
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            caption: "Add Durations",
            viewrecords: true,
            editurl: "clientArray",
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                if (selRows.length > 1) {
                    btnEdit.disabled = true;
                    btnDel.disabled = true;
                }

                else if (selRows.length == 1) {
                    btnEdit.disabled = false;
                    btnDel.disabled = false;
                }
            },




    }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#datePager", { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" }, {}, {}, {
            multipleSearch: true,
            overlay: false,
            onClose: function () {

                $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
            }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });
});
```

So now i need to access the **DateTo** value of first row in grid.. And in the defaultvalue of **DateFrom** write a function to add 1 to the obtained date from **DateTo** and display it in the **DateFrom**
 Can someone please give me any demo/help to how exactly to get this functionality working?
Thanks!

Comment: i am unable to find your data source? are you using local or from server? Does the DateFrom default value need to be fetched from previous saved row or always from first row?

Comment: this is for Creating.. So there is no db .. while editing i get it from the db(server).. locally storing it and manipulating it and sending it

Comment: btw while creating I wont have any data in grid .. so i should let them to add 1st row.. then for the second row.. it should take the **DateTo** of the previously added row and the default value of DateFrom of the second row should be the next date of **DateTo** of the previously added row..

Comment: this is details grid.. so on click  of save button i am callinh a function to send master(consists of txtboxes) and this details grid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I eventually found out.

jQuery("#GridId").jqGrid({

```
        height: 100,
        width: 1000,
        colNames: ['Date From', 'Date To', 'Type', 'Remarks'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'DateFrom', index: 'DateFrom', width: 60, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    srcformat: 'm/d/Y',

                },
                editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14 ,
                    defaultValue: function () {




                        var ids = $("#GridId").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        if (ids.length >= 1) {
                            //get first id
                            var cl = ids[0];
                            //fetch row data 
                            var rowData = $("#GridId").getRowData(cl);
                            //fetch individual cell value
                            var celValue = $("#GridId").jqGrid('getCell', cl, 'DateTo');

                            var currentTime = new Date(celValue);

                            var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                            month = month <= 9 ? "0" + month : month;

                            var day = currentTime.getDate();
                            day = day <= 9 ? "0" + day : day;

                            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                           var  months= [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

                           var ndays = months[month - 1];
                            if (month == 02)
                            {
                                if (year % 100 == 0)
                                {
                                    if (year % 400 == 0)
                                        ndays=29;
                                }
                                else
                                    if (year % 4 == 0)
                                        ndays=29;
                            }
                            day = day + 1;

                            if(day>ndays)
                            {
                                day = 1;
                                month++;
                            }
                            if (month > 12)
                            {
                                month = 1;
                                year++;
                            }                              
                            return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                        }

                        return null;

                    }
                },



            },
            {
                name: 'DateTo', index: 'DateTo', width: 80, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    srcformat: 'm/d/Y',

                },
                editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14 },

            },
            {
                name: 'Type', width: 80, editable: true, formatter: "select",
                edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Occupied:Occupied;Vacant:Vacant;Maintainance:Maintainance", defaultValue: "Occupied" },
            },
             {
                 name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 80, editable: true
             }
            ,
        ],
        // multiselect:true,
        pager: "#GridPAger",


        loadonce: true,
        sortable:true,

        sortname: 'Client',
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],

        viewrecords: true,
        editurl: "clientArray",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
            if (selRows.length > 1) {
                btnEdit.disabled = true;
                btnDel.disabled = true;
            }

            else if (selRows.length == 1) {
                btnEdit.disabled = false;
                btnDel.disabled = false;
            }
        },




    }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#GridPAger", { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" }, {}, {}, {
        multipleSearch: true,
        overlay: false,
        onClose: function () {
            // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
            // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
            // the div used by datepicker
            $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
        }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });
});
```